# Multiple namespace multiple schema xml not validating

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I am trying to validate a multiple namespace, multiple schema xml using jing. My files are as follows:
 testtype.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.my.com/testtype"
        xmlns:abcs="http://www.my.com/test1"
        xmlns:childs="http://www.my.com/childs">

 <xsd:import namespace="http://www.my.com/test1" 
       schemaLocation="abc.xsd"/>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://www.my.com/childs"
       schemaLocation="child.xsd"/>

<xsd:complexType name="testtype">
 <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element ref="childs:team" />
   <xsd:element ref="abcs:test"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

child.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://www.my.com/childs"
xmlns:why="http://www.my.com/childs">

<xs:include schemaLocation="parent.xsd" />
<xs:element name="team" type="why:baseTeam"/>
</xs:schema>
```

abc.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.my.com/test1" >

<xs:element name="test" type="xs:string">
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

parent.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.my.com/childs"
    xmlns:whys="http://www.my.com/childs">

<xsd:include schemaLocation="grandparent.xsd" />
<xsd:complexType name="baseTeam">
 <xsd:attribute name="mascot" type="whys:mascotNames" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

grandparent.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.my.com/childs">

<xsd:simpleType name="mascotNames">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:enumeration value="bengals" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="cowboys" />
  <xsd:enumeration value="patriots" />
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testtype xmlns="http://www.my.com"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.my.com/testtype  testtype.xsd
                http://www.my.com/childs  child.xsd
                                http://www.my.com/test1 abc.xsd"
            xmlns:testtype="http://www.my.com/testtype"
                xmlns:childs="http://www.my.com/childs"
            xmlns:abcs="http://www.my.com/abcs">

<childs:team mascot="cowboys"/>
<abcs:test>statement</abcs:test>
</testtype>
```

The child takes its type from parent and the parent takes it from grandparent. abc is independent namespace. testtype contains both child and abc.
The problem is when I try to validate sample.xml against testtype.xsd I get a null pointer exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
```

Can somebody tell me why there can be a null pointer exception or if there is something wrong with the xsd formation.

Thanks

Comment: A NullPointerException deep in a called product suggests a bug in that product; sometimes this can be traced to calling the product's interfaces incorrectly. When it's open source, taking a look at the source code can help. Otherwise, you're better off asking on a list specific to support of that product.

Comment: @MichaelKay I found what you're saying somewhere else also. They said it's a product error. But then can I assume my xsd's are formed correctly.

Comment: No, if the product is failing then you have no information about the correctness of your XSDs. It might be failing because they are wrong. Check them on a different XSD processor (e.g. Saxon!)

Comment: @MichaelKay ok. I'll check them. Thanks